# JQuery data binding while appending new html

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let me show this by one example

```
<div class="main_div">
    <div class="moday">
    </div>
    <button class="add_main">Add</button>
</div>
```

we have bind the class add_main the function body execute on clicking the add button is as given below

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url : "url",
  dataType : 'json',
  data : { 
    'param1'      : "param1value"
  },
  beforeSend: function(jqXHR , settings ){},
  success: function(response){
     // the response is json object.
     $(this).closest('.main_div').html('<div class="inner_data_section"></div>');
     // I have to assign the response data (that is json object ) to inner_data_seciton.
$(this).closest('.main_div').find('inner_data_section').data('data1',response);
  },
  complete: function(jqXHR , settings){}
});
```

**Problem**

AS the "inner_data_section" added later to div "main_div". The this.closest.find unable to point the inner_data_section that's why data also not bind to it.

** My Search **

I have searched and find solution that we assign data as data-data1="some value" i did this it is accessible later as well.

**But in our case we have to assign the json object (complex value) to the inner section div the data-data1="some value" works for only simple value.**

I think so i am having issue in getting jquery selector pointer the newly added html in json response.

How to cope with this problem? Just hint not complete solution.

Comment: What are you expecting `this` to be in that success method.  Have you logged it out to verify?  Odds are it is not what you expect it is. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ does offer a `context` option you can give it to define what the `this` should be inside it's callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

The default context of `this` in a jQuery ajax callback is the jQXhr object.
So trying to find DOM ancestors of it will fail.
To set it to whatever you want use the context parameter.

EDIT

Also inner_data_section this does not have the class selector `.`(RRK)

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url : "url",
  dataType : 'json',
  context: your_div, //<-- here
  data : { 
    'param1'      : "param1value"
  },
  beforeSend: function(jqXHR , settings ){},
  success: function(response){
     // the response is json object.
     $(this).closest('.main_div').html('<div class="inner_data_section"></div>');
     // I have to assign the response data (that is json object ) to inner_data_seciton.
$(this).closest('.main_div').find('.inner_data_section').data('data1',response);
  },
  complete: function(jqXHR , settings){}
});
```

Comment: Also `inner_data_section` this does not have the class selector `.`.

Answer (score 0):

I have no plan why you wanna put a json objet in a elements data but here's a example. It's definitly not clean but should work

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url : "url",
dataType : 'json',
context: your_div, //<-- here
data : { 
    'param1': "param1value"
},
beforeSend: function(jqXHR , settings ){},
success: (response) => {
    // the response is json object.
    $(this).closest('.main_div').html('<div class="inner_data_section"></div>');
    // I have to assign the response data (that is json object ) to inner_data_seciton.
    Object.keys(respone).forEach(key => $(this).closest('.main_div').find('.inner_data_section').data(key, response[key]));
},
complete: function(jqXHR , settings){}
});
```

Your just creating a data attribute for every key of your response

Answer (score 0):

The DOM is **not** the place for complex data, as you have already discovered. There are a few ways you can hack it (e.g., [Richard Fox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8996129/richard-fox)'s suggestion, but you're better off rethinking your approach. Consider a data store of some kind:

```js
const STORE = {
  data: null
};

function storeData(data){
  STORE.data = data;
}

$.ajax({
  method: 'POST,
  // ..etc
  success: storeData
});
```

From here, you could figure out how to make use of the data in a render method of some kind.